# What is Skorohod's Represntation Theorem Saying?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, soft-question

From Wikipedia:

> Let $\mu_n, n \in N$ be a sequence of probability measures on a metric space
>   S; suppose that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to some probability measure $\mu$ on S
>   as $n \to \infty$. Suppose also that the support of μ is separable. Then there
>   exist random variables $X_n, X$ defined on a common probability space $(\Omega,F, P)$ such that
>
> $X_n \xrightarrow{d}\ \mu_n$ (i.e. $μ_n$ is the distribution/law of $X_n$);
>
> $X \xrightarrow{d}\ \mu$ (i.e. $\mu$ is the distribution/law of X); and
>
> $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} x$

Can someone provide a simple, concrete example of how one would use this theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example is a version of the continuous mapping theorem which states that if $X_n \rightsquigarrow X$ then $f(X_n) \rightsquigarrow f(X)$ for a continuous function $f$. Using the a.s. representation (Skorohod's Representation theorem) there is a sequence of random variables $Y_n$ and a random variable $Y$ defined on a common probability space having the same laws as $X_n$ and $X$ s.t. $Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}Y$. The rest is pretty straightforward...

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'd like to know why this theorem is so important. Its in all advanced probability textbooks, but I never really got its importance or why we need it.

Comment: @Bey Which one?

Comment: Skorohods theorem

Comment: It's used to prove other results like any other theorem in math...

Comment: Of course, but is it used to help calculate any probabilities or formulate models, or is it really useful for proving convergence properties?

Comment: Convergence of measures is a weak form of convergence. Each $X_n$ having law $\mu_n$ may be defined on its own prob. space. So, the theorem is used when you need a stronger form of convergence (a.s.) where everything is defined on the same prob. space. So, yes, its useful for proving convergence results...

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I was just curious as to why so many advanced probability books introduce this theorem, when there are so many others in measure theory. I can see that getting a.s. as opposed to conv. in measure is indeed a result. Thanks again.